createSubscription is not working for the meeting recorded through different account of same domain
I have an appscript code to get notification with recording details on an endpoint of our application whenever a google meet recording gets created. This code is working fine when I use the same account to create & record a meeting on which my appscript is saved. However this is not working when I create and record a meeting through a different google account of the same company domain.
As per the google document Create a Google Workspace subscription
Please see the appscript code and appscript.json in this doc
 function createSubscription() {
   var spaceId = "XXXXYYYXXXXX"; //google meet space id of meeting
   const targetResource = "//meet.googleapis.com/spaces/" + spaceId;
   try {
         const eventTypes = ["google.workspace.meet.recording.v2.fileGenerated"];

         // The endpoint to deliver events to, such as a Google Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
         const pubsubTopic = "projects/my-project/topics/my_topic";
    
         // Whether to include resource data or not.
         const resourceData = false;
    
         // Call the Workspace Events API using the advanced service.
         const response = WorkspaceEvents.Subscriptions.create({
           targetResource: targetResource,
           eventTypes: eventTypes,
           notificationEndpoint: {
             pubsubTopic: pubsubTopic,
           },
           payloadOptions: {
             includeResource: resourceData
           }
     });

   } catch (e) {
     Logger.log(e);
   }
 }

appscript.json
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata",
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "WorkspaceEvents",
        "serviceId": "workspaceevents",
        "version": "v1"
      },
      {
        "userSymbol": "Calendar",
        "version": "v3",
        "serviceId": "calendar"
      },
      {
        "userSymbol": "Drive",
        "version": "v3",
        "serviceId": "drive"
      }
    ]
  },
  "webapp": {
    "access": "ANYONE",
    "executeAs": "USER_ACCESSING"
  },
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/meetings.space.created",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/meetings.space.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/meet"
  ],
  "executionApi": {
    "access": "MYSELF"
  }
}

My objective is to get artifacts of recording on an endpoint in my application whenever a google meet recording gets created by any google account of by domain. But currently this is working only for the meetings which are recorded on same account on which the appscript is running.
